# PHP & Regular expression: keyword just occurs once

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

how can I make sure a certain keyword just occurs once in the input with regular expression?

I think there is some mistakes in the expression below as I can repeat the same keywords,

```
if (!preg_match('/\b(.php?){1}\b/', $cfg_path))
    {
        $error = true;
        echo '<error elementid="cfg_path" message="PATH - make sure you have a \'.php?\' in the path."/>';
    }
```

I just want this to be true,

```
form.php?category=something or form.php?
```

but not this,

```
form.php?.php?category=something or form.php?.php?
```

please let me know how to fix it.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to espace special characters in regext. the ? is a special character and should be escaped using the \?, also the dot should be escaped with slash too.

Finally, you should not use the \b option, it is not applicable in your situation.

Try:

```
if (!preg_match('/(\.php\?){1}/', $cfg_path))
{
    $error = true;
    echo '<error elementid="cfg_path" message="PATH - make sure you have a \'.php?\' in the path."/>';
}
```

Comment: You can instead try the opposite: if (preg_match('/(\.php\?){2,}/', $cfg_path)){ bad news }

Comment: `/(\.php\?){2,}/` fails unless consecutive .php?.php? .

Comment: If more than 1 consecutive instance `/(\.php\?){2}/` is better, even better could be `/(\.php\?\s*){2}/` allowing whitespace between...

Answer (score 2):

try `preg_match_all`, which returns the number of occurrences in the string.

```
if ( preg_match_all ("~\.php\?~", $cfg_path, $match ) > 1 ){
    $error = true;
    echo '<error elementid="cfg_path" message="PATH - make sure you have a \'.php?\' in the path."/>';
}
```

More Information on `preg_match_all` here [PHP: preg_match_all - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

But, if i was writing this code, i would have avoided the use of regex completly. like

```
if (  substr_count($cfg_path, ".php?") > 1 ){
    $error = true;
    echo '<error elementid="cfg_path" message="PATH - make sure you have a \'.php?\' in the path."/>';
}
```

More on `substr_count` here: [PHP: substr_count - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Answer (score 0):

What Dmitri said, you need more escaping.

The `{1}` in regular expressions doesn't ensure that a pattern only occours once in the whole subject. It's a quantifier for the preceeding string only.

Otherwise check manually, how often it matched:

```
preg_match_all("/(\.php\??)/", $str, $m);
$matched_once = count($m[1]) == 1;
```

If you want to validate the whole string, then you have to specify the complete pattern. Use `^` or `$`. For example in your case:

```
 preg_match("/\.php(\?[^?]*|)$/", $str)
```

Where it either matches `.php?...` (with everything but question marks following), or just `.php` at the very end (`$` marks the end in regular expressions).

Comment: hmm, mario why do you want to recount the matched once's when you already get it as the return value of preg_match_all? what i mean is isn't your code the same as `$matched_once = preg_match_all (...);` ??

Comment: @AnushPrem: Hmm, you're right. Here's no point in counting the subgroup specifically.

Answer (score 0):

What is more than once? You state you only want to see it once. If what you don't want to
see is consecutive .php? .php? with possible more .php? will it be possible for more in the string?

No matter what you think when you look at a sub-string, there are the other parts of the string that have a direct influence on it.

This solves the problem:
`/^(((?!\.php\?).)*\.php\?){1}((?!\.php\?).)*$/`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samples  = (
 'form.php?category=something',
 'form.php?.php?category=something', 
 'form.php?category=something.php?',
 '.php? form.php?category=something',
 '.php? ok',
 'ok .php?',
);

for (@samples)
{
    if ( /^(((?!\.php\?).)*\.php\?){1}((?!\.php\?).)*$/x ) {
        print "Once:    $_\n\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Failed:  $_\n\n";
    }
}
```